# Match string in two character vectors and get the first matching value

Tags: r, data.table, sapply

I have the following case:
A data table of shipments (dfSysTemp) with fields: AWB, Origin, Route, HubGW.

[image: dfSysTemp]

A character vector of standard Hub 3-letter acronyms.
[image: Hubs]

The Route consists of multiple 3-letter entities separated by a hyphen (-). I need to update the HubGW field with the first Entity that exists in the list of Hubs as shown in the table.

```
What I have performed:
I used 3 functions and a For loop with sapply as shown in the code. This succeeded in getting the expected HubGW but it took around 8 minutes of processing time on 1.2M shipment records. 




# Get list of standard Hubs from Access DB
vHubs <- sqlFetch(dbMaster,"Hubs") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pull(Hub)

# create the Hubs pattern
HubsPattern=vHubs[1]
for (h in 2:length(vHubs)){
  HubsPattern=paste0(HubsPattern,"|",vHubs[h])
}

# Define a function to split the Route into Entities
SplitRoute <- function(route){
  str_split(route,"-")}`

# Define a function that takes in the split Route and return the first
# standard Hub in the Route
FetchHub1 <- function(z) {sapply(SplitRoute(z),grep,pattern=HubsPattern,value=TRUE) %>%
  unlist() %>% .[1]}

# Apply the Fetch Hub1 function to the System Temp data to assign
# the first hub for each shipment
for (i in 1:dfSysTemp[,.N]){
  dfSysTemp[i,`:=`(HubGW=FetchHub1(Route))]
}



I had to loop over all shipments using For loop since using sapply alone did not allocate the correct HubGW for the shipments. It rather allocated the first HubGW value it found to the entire list of shipments regardless of the Route.

I believe there is a better way to do it using the ‘apply’ functions that can cut the processing time considerably.

Any thoughts on this are highly appreciated.
Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split string using `strsplit` and then find which elements are in `hub`. If there is any take first otherwise return NA:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Route = c("BUD-LON-DXB-RUH", "MCT-DXB-RUH", "HEL-PRG-PAR-AUH", "AMM-JFK-LAX"),
  HubGW = c("LON", "DXB", "PAR", "AMM"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

hub <- c("LON", "DXB", "PAR", "AMM", "JFK", "LAX")

findFirst <- function(s, table){
  lgl <- s %in% table
  if(any(lgl)) s[lgl][[1]] else NA_character_
}

df$new <- vapply(strsplit(df$Route, "-"), findFirst, "character", table = hub)
```

using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, new := vapply(strsplit(df$Route, "-"), findFirst, "character", table = hub)]
```

**update**

If you don't to want to consider origin of the route for the mapping you should use this modification:

```
findFirst <- function(s, table){
  ind <- which(tail(s, -1) %in% table)
  if(length(ind) > 0) s[ind[[1]] + 1] else NA_character_
}
```

Comment: Thanks @det. This seems to work but I need the opposite kind of search. The code you wrote returns the first Hub found in the Hubs table that has a match in the Route, but I need to find the first hub in Route that has a match in the Hub table.

Comment: you are right, I've changed function `findFirst`

Comment: That's a slick, amazing solution! If I need a little tweak here such that if the Origin of AWB happens to be the same as the first identified Hub, I need to skip the first entity in Route and look for the second matching hub. For example, if AWB 1111 of Route: LON-DXB-RUH and it has an Origin of LON the identified hub should be DXB not LON although LON exists in the list of Hubs. I tried to modify the code as in below but it doesn't work: setDT(df)[Origin==new, new := vapply(strsplit(df$Route, "-")[-1], findFirst, "character", table = hub)]

Comment: instead of first identified hub in Route you want seconds one (if there is second)?

Comment: Correct. Only when Origin of the Shipment equals the first identified hub. I.e. If the shipment of origin JFK and its Route is JFK-PAR-AMM, the hub should be PAR.

Comment: what exactly is origin of shipment? First value in `Route` or first value in `hub` vector?

Comment: Origin is a separate field in the shipment record as shown in the table image.

Comment: Many thanks, @det. Your solution worked amazingly. It cut down processing time of 1.2M records to 10% of the time of my original code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, new := intersect(strsplit(Route, "-", fixed=TRUE)[[1L]], hub)[1L], by=Route]

             Route  HubGW    new
            <char> <char> <char>
1: BUD-LON-DXB-RUH    LON    LON
2:     MCT-DXB-RUH    DXB    DXB
3: HEL-PRG-PAR-AUH    PAR    PAR
4:     AMM-JFK-LAX    AMM    AMM
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Route) %>%
  mutate(new = intersect(strsplit(Route, "-", fixed=TRUE)[[1L]], hub)[1L])

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Route [4]
  Route           HubGW new  
  <chr>           <chr> <chr>
1 BUD-LON-DXB-RUH LON   LON  
2 MCT-DXB-RUH     DXB   DXB  
3 HEL-PRG-PAR-AUH PAR   PAR  
4 AMM-JFK-LAX     AMM   AMM
```